# Best way to handle errors and messages in Grails service

Tags: spring, grails

I have a Grails app, and I want to know the best way to pass errors and messages from my service layer to my controller. For example, say I click a link in my app that calls a service and brings me to a new page. On that new page in my application, I want to see a list of messages like so:

```
Information: 10 files processed successfully.

Warning: FileA is missing CreationDate

Error: FileB failed processing
Error: FileC failed processing
Error: FileD failed processing
```

I know that I can create a custom object like "ServiceReturnObject" with properties like:

```
def data
def errors
def warnings
def information
```

And have all of my services return this object.

I also know that I can use exceptions, but I am not sure if that is the right solution with multiple exceptions and multiple types of exceptions.

What is the best practice here? Examples would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return errors, I would create a custom exception class, and use it to wrap all other errors that a service can generate. That way, you only need to catch a limited number of exceptions. If you have more than one controller method/closure that needs to return errors, I would factor the code like this:

First, create your exception class and put it in src/java in the right namespace:

```
class MyException extends Exception {
    protected String code; // you could make this an int if you want
    public String getCode() { return code; }

    public MyException(String code, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Now, in your controller, create an error-handling method and wrap all calls in it

```
class MyController {
    def myService;

    def executeSafely(Closure c) {
        Map resp = [:]
        try {
            resp.data = c();
        }
        catch(MyException myEx) {
            resp.error = myEx.getMessage();
            resp.code = myEx.getCode();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            resp.error = 'Unexpected error: ' + ex.getMessage();
            resp.code = 'foo';
        }

        return resp;
    }


    def action1 = {
        def resp = executeSafely {
            myService.doSomething(params);
        }

        render resp as JSON;
    }

    def action2 = {
        def resp = executeSafely {
            myService.doSomethingElse(params);
        }

        render resp as JSON;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can have `executeSafely` convert the response to JSON and just render that directly.

Comment: Do you then throw only `MyException`s from the service?